# need to fix my php code to redirect to different pages after purchase depending con category product in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I´m working with this code but it's not working.
How can i fix it to redirect to 3 different pages for each category product (I need to set it for 3 different categories).

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );

function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase($order_product_categories) {
    $product_categories1 = jobs;
    $product_categories2 = courses;
    $product_categories3 = exchange-post;
    global $wp;

    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {

        $cat_in_cart = false;
        $order_id = isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ? intval( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) : 0;
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $product_categories = array('jobs', 'courses', 'exchange-post');

        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
            if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
                $cat_in_cart = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( $cat1_in_cart ) {
            wp_redirect( 'https://steamroute.com/post-a-job-check-out/');
        }
        elseif ( $cat2_in_cart ) {
            wp_redirect( 'https://steamroute.com/courses-checkout/');
        }
        elseif ( $cat3_in_cart ) {
            wp_redirect( 'https://steamroute.com/exchange-checkout/');
        }
        exit;

    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to find out the category of the product in your `foreach` loop ?

Comment: I have 3 category product. 'jobs', 'courses', 'exchange-post'

Comment: What is the problem/error you are getting in the above code ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this, don't forget that this code is **based on 1 category per product**, otherwise you will have to adjust it further

**p.s.** maybe you should consider this method? instead of a redirect https://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/

```php
function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    $product_categories1 = 'jobs';
    $product_categories2 = 'courses';
    $product_categories3 = 'exchange-post';

    global $wp;

    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        $cat_in_cart = false;

        $order_id = isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ? intval( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) : 0;
        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
        $product_categories = array( $product_categories1, $product_categories2, $product_categories3 );

        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $item_id = $item->get_product_id();

            if( has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $item_id ) ) {
                $cat_in_cart = true;
                $terms = get_the_terms( $item_id, 'product_cat' );

                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    // Categories by slug
                    $cat_name = $term->slug;
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        if ( $cat_in_cart ) {
            switch ($cat_name) {
                case $product_categories1:
                    wp_redirect( 'https://steamroute.com/post-a-job-check-out/');
                    break;
                case $product_categories2:
                    wp_redirect( 'https://steamroute.com/courses-checkout/');
                    break;
                case $product_categories3:
                    wp_redirect( 'https://steamroute.com/exchange-checkout/');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
```